# Where can I get list of states of all countries?

Tags: data-request, global

I need a list of all countries and their states or providences. Is there a authoritative source I can get this from?

Comment: Did you try dbpedia?

Answer (score 7):

One of the more authoritative sources will be **[UN/LOCODE](http://www.unece.org/cefact/locode/welcome.html)** (United Nations Code for Trade and Transport Locations), which is mostly used for international trade. There are CSV and Access DBs to download, and comprehensive documentation.

> Currently, UN/LOCODE includes over 103,034 locations in 249 countries and installations in international waters.

(see [my source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9627654/2327328) for more possibilities)

Answer (score 4):

If you want them as geospatial data, [**Natural Earth**](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) has a nicely prepared shapefile dataset called [Admin 1 States & Provinces (1:10m)](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-1-states-provinces/).

#### Coverage

Global. The only states that lack a subdivision in the dataset are

> Antarctica, some disputed areas, tiny island nations, and principalities such as Monaco, Andorra, Liechtenstein, and San Marino.

#### License

[Public domain](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/about/terms-of-use/)

#### Screenshot

[image: world-wide country subdivisions]

#### Attribute table

Fields `name`, `woe_label`, and `gns_name` are your best bet for a comprehensive list of descriptors/labels for each region.

[image: attribute table]